# Specific file name changes en masse

Tags: regex, bash

I need some regular expressions help. The scope of this is changing file names. Here is the pattern.

```
Super subject - Subject - Subsubject - Extra History - #number--hash.mp4
```

As you can see in the following two examples, the super subject is not always present. I would like to move the #number after the subject and remove the hash at the end.

I need a bash command or script that will accomplish this.

```
Africa - Zulu Empire - Diamonds in South Africa - Extra History - #3--JG-5otw0O8.mp4
Simón Bolívar - Defeat is Not Surrender - Extra History - #4-Ie0IoiQQFKA.mp4
```

I am looking for the output of:

```
Africa - Zulu Empire 3 - Diamonds in South Africa - Extra History.mp4
Simón Bolívar 4 - Defeat is Not Surrender - Extra History.mp4
```

I ask this question this way because I know that regex is very specific and I have not learned regex. If there is a specific tool that I can solve this myself, please let me know. This tool needs to be easy to use, please.

Comment: it is easy by some tool like awk/sed, but SO is not working in this way. what problem do you face during **writing your own codes**?

Comment: I don't know regex and do not have the time to learn it. It takes a lot of time, I am in school, and I don't know if I wish to learn regex in the end.

Comment: Is a perl script an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a perl one-liner an option for you, you can do:

**Inside the directory that owns the files**

```
perl -e '@l=glob("*.mp4");for(@l){$old=$_;@e=split(/ - /,$_);($n)=$e[-1]=~/(\d+)/;$_=($e[-5]?"$e[-5] - ":"")."$e[-4] $n - $e[-3] - $e[-2].mp4";rename$old,$_}'
```

**Explanation:**

```
perl -e '                                   # invoke perl
@l=glob("*.mp4");                           # search all mp4 in current directory
for(@l){                                    # for each file found
  $old=$_;                                  # save old name
  @e=split(/ - /,$_);                       # explode filename on ' - '
  ($n)=$e[-1]=~/(\d+)/;                     # extract the number from last element
  $_=                                       # new name
    ($e[-5]?"$e[-5] - ":"").                # first element if exists
    "$e[-4] $n - $e[-3] - $e[-2].mp4";      # all other element except the last
  rename$old,$_                             # rename the file
}'                                          # end script
```

**I suggest you to save the original directory before running this**

**In action with your 2 examples:**

```
~/devel/tmp$ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 olivier olivier 4096 mai   28 17:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 olivier olivier 4096 nov.  19  2018 ../
~/devel/tmp$touch "Africa - Zulu Empire - Diamonds in South Africa - Extra History - #3--JG-5otw0O8.mp4"
~/devel/tmp$touch "Simón Bolívar - Defeat is Not Surrender - Extra History - #4-Ie0IoiQQFKA.mp4"
~/devel/tmp$ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 olivier olivier 4096 mai   28 17:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 olivier olivier 4096 nov.  19  2018 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 olivier olivier    0 mai   28 17:13 Africa - Zulu Empire - Diamonds in South Africa - Extra History - #3--JG-5otw0O8.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 olivier olivier    0 mai   28 17:13 Simón Bolívar - Defeat is Not Surrender - Extra History - #4-Ie0IoiQQFKA.mp4
~/devel/tmp$perl -e '@l=glob("*.mp4");for(@l){$old=$_;@e=split(/ - /,$_);($n)=$e[-1]=~/(\d+)/;$_=($e[-5]?"$e[-5] - ":"")."$e[-4] $n - $e[-3] - $e[-2].mp4";rename$old,$_}'
~/devel/tmp$ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 olivier olivier 4096 mai   28 17:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 olivier olivier 4096 nov.  19  2018 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 olivier olivier    0 mai   28 17:13 Africa - Zulu Empire 3 - Diamonds in South Africa - Extra History.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 olivier olivier    0 mai   28 17:13 Simón Bolívar 4 - Defeat is Not Surrender - Extra History.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
sed 's/\([^-]*\) - \([^-]*\)\([^#]*\) - #\([0-9]*\)[^.]*\(.*\)$/\1 \4 - \2\3\5/' testdata.txt
```

**testdata.txt**

```
Africa - Zulu Empire - Diamonds in South Africa - Extra History - #3--JG-5otw0O8.mp4
Simón Bolívar - Defeat is Not Surrender - Extra History - #4-Ie0IoiQQFKA.mp4
```

**output**

```
Africa 3 - Zulu Empire - Diamonds in South Africa - Extra History.mp4 
Simón Bolívar 4 - Defeat is Not Surrender - Extra History.mp4
```

**explanation**

```
sed 's/            # use sed substitution
\([^-]*\)          # store all characters unequal - in arg1 (\2)
 -                 # ignore separator
\([^-]*\)          # store all characters unequal - in arg2 (\2)
\([^#]*\)          # store all characters unequal # in arg1 (\3)
 - #               # ignore separator
\([0-9]*\)         # store number in arg4 (\4)
[^.]*              # ignore all chars unequal .
\(.*\)             # store suffix in arg5 (\5)
/\1 \4 - \2\3\5/'  # create output
```

**Script to rename files in local directory**

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.mp4; do
    newname=$(sed 's/\([^-]*\) - \([^-]*\)\([^#]*\) - #\([0-9]*\)[^.]*\(.*\)$/\1 \4 - \2\3\5/' <<<"$file")
    mv "$file" "$newname"
done
```

Comment: this is almost it but for the Simón Bolívar - Defeat is Not Surrender - Extra History - #4-Ie0IoiQQFKA.mp4 I would like it to be Simón Bolívar 4 - Defeat is Not Surrender - Extra History.mp4

Comment: sure - i have expand my solution ;-)